# Joining dataframe with dataframes or creating new variabels

Tags: r, join

This is my data:

```
### Data 1
df_1 <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2022-10-27","2022-07-28", "2022-04-28")))
df_1
### Data 2
df_2 <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2022-09-12","2022-06-13", "2022-03-15","2022-01-15","2021-10-21")), ratio = c(2.12,4.43,1.23,9.89,7.50))
df_2

### What I want to have:

df_3 <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2022-10-27","2022-07-28", "2022-04-28" )), 
                   ratio_past_1 =c(2.12,4.43,1.23), 
                   ratio_past_2 = c(4.43,1.23,9.89), 
                   ratio_past_3 = c(1.23,9.89,7.50),
                   ratio_past_4 = c(9.89,7.50,NA), 
                   ratio_past_5 = c(7.50,NA,NA))
df_3
```

What I know:

1. Dates from df_1 always greater than in df_2 pairwise compared
2. df_1 date_i is the same peride as in df_2 date_i

What I want:

1. Take the dates from df_1 as date in df_3
2. Create new variables based on the obervsation in df_2 (ratio) after the date
   variable in df_1

Comment: So, now that the dates are different, we have to ask "How do we join them?" Can we be sure that `df_1` and `df_2` have the same number of rows, and we just need to line them up in the right order? Or do we need to do checking to make sure that, e.g., `df_2`'s latest date `"2022-10-12"` falls between the `"2022-10-27","2022-07-28"` dates from `df1` and then put it accordingly?

Comment: this seems like a non-equi join: stackoverflow.com/q/64362881/3358272, stackoverflow.com/q/64539945/3358272

Comment: @r2evans Its not the same. I had a look on it.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas. No we can not be sure, that both have the same length. I tried it with your solution with case_when but it didnt work. No, actually date "2022-10-12" in df_2 is actually date "2022-10-27" in df_2.

Comment: Okay, if this needs to work with data frames of different lengths, then I think you should edit your example to make the inputs different lengths and show what you want to happen in that case. (But also I agree with r2evans - seems like a non-equi join is the right first step. It would be great if you could explain **why** you don't think so.)

Comment: I edit my example to make things clearer. I hope this helps. Any tips are welcome. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update2: Second suggestion:
This one is better with having own function. But I am not happy with hard coding of ratio_past_1: ratio_past_5

```
library(dplyr)
# lookup vector
vector_lookup <- c("period1" = 1:4, "period2" = 5:8, "period3" = 9:12)

# define function
add_period_column <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    mutate(month = month(ymd(date))) %>% 
    mutate(
      period = case_when(
        month %in% vector_lookup[period1] ~ "period1",
        month %in% vector_lookup[period2] ~ "period2",
        month %in% vector_lookup[period3] ~ "period3",
        TRUE ~ NA_character_
      )
    )
}

# create list of data frames
df_list <- list(df_1, df_2)

df_list_period <- lapply(df_list, add_period_column)

# join data frames
df_join <- Reduce(function(x, y) left_join(x, y, by = "period"), df_list_period)
df_join %>% 
  mutate(ratio_past_1 = ratio,
         ratio_past_2 = lead(ratio,1),
         ratio_past_3 = lead(ratio,2),
         ratio_past_4 = lead(ratio,3),
         ratio_past_5 = lead(ratio,4)
  ) %>% 
  select(date = date.x, contains("_"))
```

Update: first attempt.
here we create a named vector as a look_up ressource. The next thing is that we define our periods and join by `period`

```
vector_lookup <- c("period1" = 1:4, "period2" = 5:8, "period3" = 9:12)

df_1 %>%
  mutate(month = month(ymd(date))) %>% 
  mutate(
    period = case_when(
      month %in% vector_lookup[period1] ~ "period1",
      month %in% vector_lookup[period2] ~ "period2",
      month %in% vector_lookup[period3] ~ "period3",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  ) %>% 
  left_join(df_2 %>% 
              mutate(month = month(ymd(date))) %>% 
              mutate(
                period = case_when(
                  month %in% vector_lookup[period1] ~ "period1",
                  month %in% vector_lookup[period2] ~ "period2",
                  month %in% vector_lookup[period3] ~ "period3",
                  TRUE ~ NA_character_
                )), by = "period") %>% 
  mutate(ratio_past_1 = ratio,
         ratio_past_2 = lead(ratio,1),
         ratio_past_3 = lead(ratio,2),
         ratio_past_4 = lead(ratio,3),
         ratio_past_5 = lead(ratio,4)
         ) %>% 
  select(date = date.x, contains("_"))
```

```
  date ratio_past_1 ratio_past_2 ratio_past_3 ratio_past_4 ratio_past_5
1 2022-10-27         2.12         7.50         4.43         1.23         9.89
2 2022-10-27         7.50         4.43         1.23         9.89           NA
3 2022-07-28         4.43         1.23         9.89           NA           NA
4 2022-04-28         1.23         9.89           NA           NA           NA
5 2022-04-28         9.89           NA           NA           NA           NA
```

Maybe something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df_1 %>%
  mutate(x = format(as.Date(date), "%Y-%m")) %>% 
  left_join(df_2 %>% 
              mutate(x = format(as.Date(date), "%Y-%m")), by = "x") %>% 
  mutate(ratio_past_1 = ratio,
         ratio_past_2 = lead(ratio,1),
         ratio_past_3 = lead(ratio,2)) %>% 
  select(date = date.x, contains("_"))

        date ratio_past_1 ratio_past_2 ratio_past_3
1 2022-10-27         2.12         4.43         1.23
2 2022-07-28         4.43         1.23           NA
3 2022-04-28         1.23           NA           NA
```

Comment: One question. Does this work if the month differ. For example: In df_1 it is "2022-05-31" and in df_2 "2022-04-30"?

Comment: This depends on your definition of time series. Actually it is defined within one month. We just have to define the rang of time series!

Comment: I have no clue. In my dataset the longest range between the dates in df_1 and df_2 is 3 months. So. df_1: "2022-12-30" and in df_2: "2022-15-09" and this is the same period. I mean in mutate I dont need the day for comparison. I understand the solution, only not the part with the date. Exactly where I can change the range.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-equi join plus a reshape/pivot.

```r
library(dplyr) # dplyr_1.1.0 or later, for `join_by` and `.by=`
df_1 %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  left_join(df_2, join_by(date >= date), suffix = c("", ".y")) %>%
  mutate(cn = row_number(), .by = rn) %>%
  select(-date.y, -rn) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = date, names_from = "cn", values_from = "ratio", names_prefix = "ratio_past_")
# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#   date       ratio_past_1 ratio_past_2 ratio_past_3
#   <date>            <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 2022-10-27         2.12         4.43         1.23
# 2 2022-07-28         4.43         1.23        NA   
# 3 2022-04-28         1.23        NA           NA
```

Comment: I got the Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs. Do you know why? Seems something to be with dplyr. Thanks

Comment: No, I have no idea. I'm not using it here, so I don't know how it is introduced into the code in your use. FWIW, `dplyr_1.1.1` and `tidyr_1.3.0` on R-4.2.3.

Comment: Ok. Then I have to look. Thank you